# error 1064 mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema al crear un procedimiento almacenado me tira error 1064

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertar_Grupo(
IN _Codigo_Grupo INT(10),
IN _Nombre_Grupo MEDIUMTEXT,
IN _Descripcion_Grupo MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO grupo(Codigo_Grupo,Nombre_Grupo,Descripcion_Grupo)
VALUES ( _Codigo_Grupo, _Nombre_Grupo, _Descripcion_Grupo);
END
```

eso es lo que tengo me podrian decir donde esta el error¿

> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 7

eso me tira la consola

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es debido a que:

- Te hace falta el **`DELIMITER`** para establecer cuando inicia y termina tu grupo de sentencias SQL
- Puedes opcionalmente usar como delimitador el símbolo de **`//`**

Quedando de este modo:

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertar_Grupo(
IN _Codigo_Grupo INT(10),
IN _Nombre_Grupo MEDIUMTEXT,
IN _Descripcion_Grupo MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO grupo(Codigo_Grupo,Nombre_Grupo,Descripcion_Grupo)
VALUES ( _Codigo_Grupo, _Nombre_Grupo, _Descripcion_Grupo);
END;
//
```